# Angular rxjs: keep alive subcriptions handling http errors

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

When a button is clicked an http request is called:

```
let saveClickPush$ = Observable
    .fromEvent(this.saveButton.nativeElement, 'click')
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.service.push(this.user)),
        share()
    );
```

So, when it's clicked, I create two observables:

```
this.pushed$ = saveClickPush$.pipe(this.pushUser(), this.handleEmptyUser());
this.error$ = saveClickPush$.pipe(this.handleError<never>());
```

where:

```
private handleError = <T>() => catchError<T, Array<{code: string, message: string}>>((error: ResponseError) => Observable.of(error.errors));
private handleEmptyUser = <T>() => catchError<T, AdministrationUser>(() => Observable.of(UserComponent.EMPTY_USER));
```

What I'm trying to do is when an error is raised:

1. An empty user is emitted on `pushed$` observable.
2. A detailed error message is emitted on `error$`.

However, **when an http error is raised an http request is not called again when I click on button**. It seems like all subscribers are unsubscribed when an http error is raised previously in spite of I've tried to handle errors.

My service is:

```
public push(user: AdministrationUser): Observable<AdministrationUser> {
    const buildURL = () => map((userId: string) => this.buildPushURL(userId));

    return Observable.of(user.id)
        .pipe(
            buildURL(),
            switchMap((url: string) => this.http.post(url, user)
                .pipe(
                    map(() => user),
                    catchError((error: Response) => Observable.throw(<ResponseError>error.json()))
                )
            )
        );
}
```

So, when an http error is raised:

1. It's catch but raised again returning `Observable.throw` handling `error response`.
2. On `pushed$` observable, it's also catch using

Answer (score 0):

Since you re throw the error in your `this.service.push()` stream, to not break the click stream you will have to contain and catch the error in inner observable

```
let saveClickPush$ = Observable
    .fromEvent(this.saveButton.nativeElement, 'click')
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.service.push(this.user).pipe(catchError(e=>of(e))),
        share()
    );
```

Comment: If you return an `of(e)`, `error$` will never emit error detail, will not?

Comment: You can throw a custom error message then conditionally handles it